# Convergence of subsequence defined by geometric sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a real sequence. Suppose that for any geometric sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_1>1$ and the common ratio greater than $1$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_{[a_n]}=l$, where $[\cdot]$ is the floor function. Show that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $l$.

Here, floor function $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. If the condition “geometric sequence” is replaced by "arithmetic sequence", then the problem is easy to solve because finite many arithmetic sequences will cover all indices; for example, we may take $a_1$ and the common difference $d$ to be arbitrary positive integers, and then $d$ subsequences will cover the whole sequence. An typical example is the even subsequence and the odd subsequence.

However, is this idea still applied to “geometric sequence”? If we only consider all index sequences $\{a_n\}$ within integers, it will certainly fail because any prime integer must be the first term of some sequence. Hence, we have to consider the case when the first term $a_1$ or the common ratio is not an integer. Maybe it is related to elementary number theory, isn't it?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, this is a good thought. But the last sentence seems not easy to proof.

Comment: Yeah - I deleted it because I decided I'd found a counter-example, but then I realized it wasn't, so I reposted the comment, thought I'd found a counter-example again, and deleted it again (obviously not before you saw it), then realized the counter-example still didn't work. This much is true though: The statement is equivalent to saying that for any infinite set of natural numbers, there is some geometric $\{a_n\}$ for which $\{\lfloor a_n\rfloor\}$ contains infinitely many members of the set.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, but how to prove for the statement that any infinite set of natural numbers, there is some geometric $\{a_n\}$ for which $\{⌊a_n⌋\}$ contains infinitely many members of the set? It looks like an elementary number theory question.

Comment: It involves basic number theory, but the core is analysis. Show that the double sequence of ratios of the elements of the infinite set has a cluster point other than $1$. Or if you can find an infinite set with no cluster points, you can use it to form a counter-example by defining $x_n = 1$ if $n$ is in the set, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, I am not able to understand your idea. Could you please give more details?